# How to add for loop in python port scanner script?

Tags: python, linux

I have written python port scanner in linux platform.. Just want to know how can I add for loop to check 0 - 65535 ports of target ip ? please advice

```
import os

def get_nmap(options,ip):
    command = "nmap" + options + "" + ip
    process = os.popen(command)
    result = str(process.read())
    return result

print(get_nmap('-F','target ip'))
```

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: And BTW, you haven't written the port scanner, you've written wrapper around `nmap`. And `nmap` already supports the port range via `-p` option, f.e. `nmap -p1-65535 target`.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1: nmap switches**

You could accomplish that only using `nmap` options.
From the nmap(1) [man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nmap) page:

```
PORT SPECIFICATION AND SCAN ORDER:
  -p <port ranges>: Only scan specified ports
    Ex: -p22; -p1-65535; -p U:53,111,137,T:21-25,80,139,8080,S:9
```

**Option 2: python loop**

You should reimplement your method to accept a port as well:

```
def get_nmap(options,ip,port):
    command = "nmap" + "-p" + str(port) + " " + options + "" + ip
    process = os.popen(command)
    result = str(process.read())
    return result
```

And then call it in a loop:

```
for port in range(0, 65535):
    print(get_nmap('', ip, port))
```

Note: `-F` won't work with a specific port range, since it defines:

> -F: Fast mode - Scan fewer ports than the default scan

Comment: it gives me following error - File "nmap.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(get_nmap('-F','192.168.234.135',port))
  File "nmap.py", line 4, in get_nmap
    command = "nmap " + "-p" + port + " " + options + " " + ip
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: also can we use -F with -p at the same time ?

Comment: it says cannot use -F with -p no result given .. any reason for that ?

Comment: @Alex, fixed answer. You can't do that because -F uses predefined ports and it cannot be used with -p

Comment: how can i print only open ports ? its just keep on scanning and just flashing open / close ports i cant figure out which ports are open ?

Answer (score -1):

Use a for loop, and make sure you have spaces in the correct place for the command part.

```
import os

def get_nmap(options,ip):
    command = "nmap " + options + " " + ip
    process = os.popen(command)
    result = str(process.read())
    return result

for ip in range(0, 65535):
    print(get_nmap('-F', str(ip)))
```

Comment: 0-65535 are port numbers, not IP addresses.